# Hide logcat left side menu in android studio

Tags: android, android-studio, logcat

I am facing one strange issue.

I am not able to get my menu list which is generally located on the left side and besides to logcat.

Is there any shortcut or place from where I can enable it.

For reference please check the attached screenshot.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have just hidden the toolbar:

Go here:

[image: Settings]

Then select `Show Toolbar`:

[image: Show Toolbar]

Answer (score 2):

Choose `Floating mode` then `Docker mode`.

Answer (score 1):

Click on top `settings icon` and click on `Show Toolbar`.

[image: Image Description]

You should be able to see it again